# Is it possible to log all operation, automatically?

Tags: h2

Is it possible to log all operation on specific table? For example, any row insertion/update/delete are logged automatically. That log should only readable/writable by admin.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so using `TRIGGERS`:

http://h2database.com/html/features.html#triggers

H2 allows for "injecting" Java classes as triggers, which makes logging of particular events quite simple and extensible